# AngularJS 2 and webcomponents, emulating and polyfills

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, web-component, shadow-dom

The AngularJS 2 has the capacity to use Shadow DOM native that is part of web components when setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` as I understand...

But this give some questions:

- When `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` will it fallback to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` when the browser doesn't support Shadow DOM?
- Is it able to use the webcomponents polyfill when the browser doesn't support Shadow DOM and is set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **no fallback** from `ViewEncapsulation.Native` to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` when the browser doesn't support native shadow DOM. This will result in runtime errors.

If you want to use `Native` you can load the [webcomponents polyfills](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) and enable shadow DOM like shown in [Global Polymer settings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings).

Comment: Have I to load Polymer in order to use the webcomponents polyfill?

Comment: No, the polyfills are an independent library. You should be aware that Angular2 doesn't have a good story yet for styling native shadow DOM (theming) like for example CSS variables and mixins in Polymer.